# Divide a number into unequal parts in order to balance vector in r

Tags: r

I have a vector made of 10 random integers like this:

`a <- c(400,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,13)`

and I have a random integer:

`n <- 100`

My goal is to divide `n` so that the components of `a` have the smallest differences between them. The desired output in this case is `c(400,14,14,14,14,13,13,13,13,13)` (13+13+13+13+12+12+12+12 = 100)

My approach was to use a recursive function:

```
    dis <- function(n,a){

      a[which.min(a)] <- a[which.min(a)] + 1 

      n <- n -1

      if(!n){
        return(a)
      }

      dis(n,a)

   }

   dis(100, c(400,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,13))
```

But I found problems when `n` is larger, e.g. when `n` is 1000 I get this message

> Error: C stack usage  7969684 is too close to the m

I'm not sure if there is something to avoid recursion, maybe an arithmetic solution, or another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it as a `while` loop rather than using deeply nested recursion?

```r
dis <- function(n,a) {

  while(n > 0)
  {
    a[which.min(a)] <- a[which.min(a)] + 1 
    n <- n - 1
  }
  a
}

dis(100, c(400,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,13))
#> [1] 400  14  14  14  14  13  13  13  13  13

dis(10000, c(400,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,13))
#> [1] 1043 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect, I don't see what's the problem with "deeply nested recursion" in r

Comment: @Emeeus the problem is simply that R refuses to go beyond a certain level of recursion. I didn't get a stack usage limit on your code, but I got an error due to the depth of recursion. I think this is controllable to some extent in options, but then its difficult to get your code to run on other PCs etc. There is a time cost to function calls in R, so if there are simpler linear ways to solve a problem without thousands of function calls, it is often more efficient to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need some minor modification over your recursive function, e.g.,

```
dis <- function(n, a) {
  if (!n) {
    return(a)
  } else {
    a[which.min(a)] <- a[which.min(a)] + 1
    dis(n-1, a)
  }
}
```

**Example**

```
> dis(100,a)
 [1] 400  14  14  14  14  13  13  13  13  13

> dis(1000,a)
 [1] 400 114 114 114 114 113 113 113 113 113
```